# Why data object is reinitialized while CSR in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

```
async created() {
    if (process.server) {
      try {
        const data = // API call to fetch FAQs 
        this.faqs = data.faqs
        console.log(this.faqs, ' server')
      } catch (e) {}
    } else {
      console.log(this.faqs, 'client')
    }
  },
```

Consider the above code with Nuxt.js and SSR enabled. I know it is intended behaviour of Vue to call created hook in both SSR and CSR.
But as we can see in the above code, the **faqs** in data object are mutated in server side and stores the result from API.
But when hydration takes place in client side this faqs is set to its initial value which is NULL.

Can some explain this behaviour. Thanks in advance !

Comment: It is fetching on server, but fetching nothing on the client, while still hydrating the view. Hence why this is `null`. Why do you even test if it's a server? You can also disable fetch on the server if needed: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/fetch#options

Comment: You seem to expect that server-side rendered Nuxt app will somehow automatically send all the data loaded during SSR to the client. This is not the case. You should probably read [this](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching)

Comment: @MichalLevý Thanks for the answer. fetch() is called on server side and we can set the data and it will not lost in client side, we can't do same thing with created() hook. Just wanted to know then why Vue is calling beforeMount and created hook on server side? Would you please tell any use case where created hook is useful in ssr?

Comment: `created` is called on the server. `beforeMount` is called only on the client as shown in the [Nuxt lifecycle](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#nuxt-lifecycle). Also, in Nuxt you do have `fetch()`, `asyncData()`, so those are usually more used in Nuxt. `created()` is heavily used in Vue because it helps having your requests running while your page is created and mounted.